# How to center text next to image?

Tags: html, css

I have this demo https://jsfiddle.net/447cv32f/ . I want to center this circle and text. Any suggestion how to do this?

```
<div class="public_profile">
    <div class="profile_image business">
        <img src="img/realestate_icon.png" />
    </div>
    <h4>BUSINESS ACCOUNT</h4>
    <h3>Sunny Real Estate Sarl.</h3>
    <hr class="business_line" />
    <h5>VERIFIED USER</h5>
    <h5 class="registered">Registered on January 27th 2016</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you wish to position the circle and text horizontally or vertically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the text with a div and move the flex styles to the `.public_profile` container

```css
.public_profile {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.public_profile .profile_image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.public_profile .profile_image.business {
  background-color: #fdb902;
}
.public_profile .profile_image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.public_profile h4 {
  font-family: 'OpenSans-ExtraBold';
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #a1d15f;
  margin: 0;
}
.public_profile h3 {
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Light';
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  margin: 0;
}
.public_profile h5 {
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Regular';
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #4d5663;
  margin: 0;
}
.public_profile h5.registered {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #4c4d4d;
}
hr.business_line {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 2px solid #a1d15f;
}
```

```html
<div class="public_profile">
  <div class="profile_image business">
    <img src="img/realestate_icon.png" />
  </div>
  <div>

    <h4>BUSINESS ACCOUNT</h4>
    <h3>Sunny Real Estate Sarl.</h3>
    <hr class="business_line" />
    <h5>VERIFIED USER</h5>
    <h5 class="registered">Registered on January 27th 2016</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

(edited version:)

https://jsfiddle.net/up7n90fc/

Put a wrapper around all that text, define its content elements as block elements and center them:

```
<div class="public_profile">
    <div class="profile_image business">
        <img src="img/realestate_icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="wrap1">
      <h4>BUSINESS ACCOUNT</h4>
      <h3>Sunny Real Estate Sarl.</h3>
      <hr class="business_line" />
      <h5>VERIFIED USER</h5>
      <h5 class="registered">Registered on January 27th 2016</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.wrap1 > * {
  display: block;
}
```

(you can add a width to the wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

Take another element with `display:inline-block` and make them center by giving text-align:center to your wrap (`public_profile`).

**for example**:

html

```
<div class="public_profile">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="profile_image business">
      <img src="img/realestate_icon.png" />
    </div>
    <h4>BUSINESS ACCOUNT</h4>
    <h3>Sunny Real Estate Sarl.</h3>
    <hr class="business_line" />
    <h5>VERIFIED USER</h5>
    <h5 class="registered">Registered on January 27th 2016</h5>
  </div>

</div>
```

css

```
.center {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/447cv32f/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a container `div` around the text next to the circle, then give the parent container `display:flex`, `align-items:center` and `justify-content:center`

i.e.
HTML

```
<div class="public_profile">
  <div class="profile_image business">
    <img src="img/realestate_icon.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="profile-container">
    <h4>BUSINESS ACCOUNT</h4>
    <h3>Sunny Real Estate Sarl.</h3>
    <hr class="business_line" />
    <h5>VERIFIED USER</h5>
    <h5 class="registered">Registered on January 27th 2016</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.public_profile{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  border:solid 1px red;
}

.public_profile .profile-container {
  border:solid 1px green;
}

.public_profile .profile_image{
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px; 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.public_profile .profile_image.business{
    background-color: #fdb902;
}
.public_profile .profile_image img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.public_profile h4{
    font-family: 'OpenSans-ExtraBold';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #a1d15f;
    margin: 0;
}
.public_profile h3{
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Light';
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    margin: 0;
}
.public_profile h5{
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Regular';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #4d5663;
    margin: 0;
}
.public_profile h5.registered{
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #4c4d4d;
}
hr.business_line{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 2px solid #a1d15f;
}
```

(note: borders are purely for display purposes)

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/hh5Ljwko/)

EDIT: Ok, so I misunderstood slightly, I also vertically centered the text next to the circle as well as horizontally centering everything, the `align-items:center` in the container vertically centers everything, and the `justify-content:center` horizontally centers it, just use whichever one solves your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.text{text-align:center;}
</style>

<div class="public_profile">
<div class="profile_image business">
    <img src="img/realestate_icon.png" />
</div>
<div class="text">
<h4>BUSINESS ACCOUNT</h4>
<h3>Sunny Real Estate Sarl.</h3>
<hr class="business_line" />
<h5>VERIFIED USER</h5>
<h5 class="registered">Registered on January 27th 2016</h5>
</div>
</div>
```